# Live editing in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I want to edit a web page in Google Chrome, the problem is that there are no "Sources" for that web page, i.e. it contains only one html page. Tell me if I am making a mistake, I know it can be from the Sources tab but there are no CSS or JS files, its just a simple html page.

Thank You

Comment: use developer tool to see where sources and page is. Press F12 for it.

Comment: So you want to add CSS /JS to the page or do you simply want to edit the HTML?

Comment: @Cracker there is no file under sources tab and I only want to edit html, not css/js.

Comment: Copy the whole code that you see by using developer tool. Create new txt.file on your desktop. Paste all code to inside of that file then chamge file extension to html. You are not available to edit that page.

Comment: well that's not a nice solution but still thanks for telling that its not available.

Comment: you should be able to see all the sources, if you dont, then there are none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Chrome press F12, Select Elements tab, navigate to the element you want to edit. Right click > Edit as HTML and at the right, in the styles, add a new rule to apply on the page.

Answer (score 1):

On Chrome press F12, Select `Elements` tab, navigate to the element you want to edit. Right click > Edit as HTML and do whatever you want here.

[image]

Comment: i wanted to edit the css instead of the html, now i've figured it out, but still thanks.

Comment: Then post your own answer or put the answer at the end of your question so everyone will know.